# Doctrine query from array

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I have an html form with multiple select fields. I'm trying to build sql query for json endpoint to find results based on that form selection. So i'm trying to build link with selected query params :

Examples:

**$searchArr1** = *['city' => london, 'type' => 'flat', 'material' => wood]* 
**$searchArr2** = *['city' => paris, 'material' => 'wood']*

1) **url1**: *name.com/search?city=london&type=flat&material=wood*
2) **url2**: *name.com/search?city=paris&material=wood*
and so on.

how do i build doctrine sql query with it ?

p.s. I also tried including empty string "" and "*" for wildcard values if the user makes no selection in a given field but it didn't register the way I wanted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any relevant code, your desired goals and what you've achieved so far. How exactly is doctrine tied to this? What does it mean "*it didn't register the way I wanted*"? There are too many unknowns at the moment for us to help you.